# echo a table horizontally php

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have been trying to work this out for hours and I’m not sure how to achieve the correct result, hopefully someone will be able to help me.

I have the below code that will echo the result is a table vertically, but I want the cells next to each other horizontally, how can I achieve this?

```
<?php     
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' width='100%' bordercolor='000099'border='solid'>
";
echo '<div style="width:100%;">'; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($boxlink))
echo "<tr>";
{

echo "<td>" . $row['page_page_title'] . "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
echo '</div>'; 
?>
```

Brill that worked thanks a lot, why is it the small things can cause such a problem!

Comment: remove your TR tags in the loop which create new rows, and put them outside the loop

Comment: Don't use `border='1' cellpadding='1' width='100%' bordercolor='000099'`, it is ancient html syntax!  Use styles instead, which you are also using below.

Answer (score 2):

Move your tr tags outside of the loop. Each time a tr tag is seen it makes another row.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php     
echo '<div style="width:100%;">'; 
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='1' width='100%' bordercolor='000099'border='solid'>
";
echo "<tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($boxlink))
{
echo "<td>" . $row['page_page_title'] . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
echo '</div>'; 
?>
```